Star Trek 2009 K/S fanfic where they play a game of questions to pass the time
This fanfic was either on fanfiction.net or ao3, as those are the sires I frequent most for fanfics.
I'm fairly sure it was the Star Trek 2009 universe and had only Kirk and Spock in it. Both have been captured and shackled to a wall. Kirk gets bored and complains and Spock is sorry that he cannot help as his chess board is elsewhere.
Kirk suggests a gane of questions and they begin. But Spock eventually reveals that he can free himself from his confines.
Kirk tells Spock to free him but Spock tells him no and proceeds to tease him. Kirk is eventually freed, says Spock is a 'goddamn tease' and they proceed to kanoodle.

Have you already tried using the search filters on either fan fiction website?
